# How would you correct this sentence?

Tags: verbs

> She left an hour ago. You should be here earlier.

This question was in my grammar exam yesterday, and I’m not sure about my answer.

Since it expresses expectation, I chose to make it this way: She left an hour ago. She should be here early.

However, the sentence still feels off. I thought that maybe the tense I chose is wrong, and it supposed to be: She should have been here earlier. Is this the correct answer? Or do both work?

What is the best answer grammatically and academically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They may want this:

> She left an hour ago. You should have been here earlier.

That is, if you had been here earlier, you wouldn't have missed her.

Comment: So does my answer considered wrong?  By the way thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Actually, I can imagine a scenario where your answer would make sense: *She left home an hour ago. She should get here early.* But your answer requires changing two different things in the original: *earlier* to *early*, and *you* to *she*.  My suggestion changes only the tense of the verb.

Comment: Thank you so much!